# Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(av) = af(v)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ but $f$ is not linear.

Basically, we need to find a function that adheres to the linear property of Homogeneity (closure under scalar multiplication) but not the linear property of Additivity (closure under vector addition). I'm having difficulties coming up with such a function as I can't find one that has the homogeneity property but not the Additivity property. I've tried polynomials in $P(\mathbb{R^2})$, trigonometric functions, etc. and none of them seem to work. My other guess is a piecewise function, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: What polynomials did you test?  Was the problem that it got you $a^2$ instead of $a$  out in front? Bet you can make that $a^2$ an $a$ somehow.

Comment: $f(\vec{x}) = \alpha(\vec{x})\vec{x}$ where $\alpha : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is any function that depends only on the angle $\vec{x}$ makes with the $x$-axis and invariant under the reflection, i.e. $\alpha(-\vec{x}) = \alpha(\vec{x})$. For example, $\alpha( (x,y) ) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @Evan thanks for pointing that out, I'll see if that works

Comment: Just a little notational point. We usually use the symbol $\to$ between the two sets, e.g. $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. We use the symbol $\mapsto$ when dealing with an element, e.g. $\operatorname{f} : x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: @Fly by Night thanks for letting me know the correct notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take $f(x,y) = ( x^3 + y^3)^{1/3} $

$$ f(ax, ay) = ((ax)^3 + (ay)^3)^{1/3} = a f(x, y) $$

But,

$f(1,0) = 1 = f(0,1) $ and $f(1,1) = (2)^{1/3} $

It is then easy to extend this function to a new one $F: R^2 \to R^2 $ such that $F( \underline{x} ) = ( f( \underline{x}), 0 ) $ where $\underline{x} = (x,y) $

Comment: Then we have $f(ax,ay)=|a|f(x,y)$ which was not what the OP wanted!

Comment: This only works for $a > 0$, doesn't it? $f(-1,0) = \sqrt{(-1)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1 \neq (-1)f(1,0)$.

Comment: The OP asks for a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, not to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @achillehui True, but it would be easy to obtain one: if $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the requirement that $f(av)=af(v)$, then one can define $\tilde{f}(v)=(f(v),0)$.

Comment: should work now

Comment: @Citizen It does; you can make it into a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself, rather than to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example. Let $f(x, y) = (0,0)$ when $x\neq 0$ and $f(0, y) = (0,y)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can let $f((r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta))$ be equal to $r g(\theta)$, where $g$ is any $\pi$-antiperiodic function you like.  For instance, let $g(\theta)=\sin^3\theta e_x$ to obtain $$f(v)=r(v)\sin^3\theta(v)e_x=\frac{(v\cdot e_y)^3 e_x}{|v|^2}.$$

Comment: What is a $\pi$-antiperiodic function?

Comment: @StVincent $g(\theta+\pi) = -g(\theta)$

Comment: @achille hui oh I see, thanks.