# How to find a nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is almost linear in the sense $f(\alpha (a,b))=\alpha f(a,b)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find a nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(\alpha (a,b))=\alpha f(a,b)$ for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

I can't find anything.

#### Context

The requirement $f(\alpha (a,b))=\alpha f(a,b)$ says that $f$ respects the scalar multiplication, just as linear maps do. In particular, $f$ is *homogeneous* of degree $1$. To make it nonlinear, one has to somehow destroy the additive property $f(a+c,b+d)=f(a,b)+f(c,d)$.

Comment: A duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/870478/ but the answer there isn't upvoted, so I can't vote to close. (The example there works for negative scalar multiplication too, not just homogeneity).

Comment: Side note: over $\mathbb{R}$, every scalar multiple of $\vec{v}$ is a a limit of rational scalar multiples of $\vec{v}$. And if additivity holds for a transformation, then it's easy to show that preservation of scalar multiplication by a rational number holds. So if you had the opposite task (seeking a transformation with additivity but not scalar preservation) then it would be impossible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106785/an-additive-map-that-is-not-a-linear-transformation-over-mathbbr-when-ma/106790#106790).

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh yes, I should have added "continuous" to my note, which relies on reals being approached by a sequence of rationals.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/540876/

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis that $f(\alpha\vec x)=\alpha f(\vec x)$ is equivalent to requiring that $f$ is linear on each line through the origin.  You can map these lines to other lines in nonlinear ways.  E.g., you could rotate a vector with polar angle $\theta$ by an angle of $\sin^2\theta$ (or any other nonconstant $\pi$-periodic function of $\theta$):

$$(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\mapsto (r\cos(\theta+\sin^2(\theta)),r\sin(\theta+\sin^2(\theta)).$$

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice all that happened in this thread in the last 20 minutes or so.  There is some inadvertent similarity to JHance's answer, and I hadn't seen from 900sit-ups's comment that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find a function $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ that is non linear and satisfies your condition. Then take $$f(a,b) = (g(a,b),0)$$

> Try $$g(a,b) = \begin{cases}\frac{a^2}b & b \ne 0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: you beat me to it... Nice answer. But please do remember to deal with negative numbers...

Comment: Currently working from a phone. The idea is clear. Many functions to choose. One is $a^2/b$ for $b$ non zero and $0$ otherwise. Can't easily write that from a phone

Comment: Another is $a \;\text{signum}(b)$.

Comment: I agree with $a^2/b$.  But with $a\,\mathrm{sgn}(b)$, doesn't it not work for negative $\alpha$? $f(1,1)=f(-1,-1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You can define f as follows : $f(0,y)=(0,y)$ for any $y$, and $f(x,y)=(y,0)$ for any $y$,whenever $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As observed by others, in order for this to happen the function must fail to be additive. Now, one way to think about such problems is to ask the following: given my hypotheses on the function, how much data determines the function?

For example, in a linear function it is a standard observation that specifying $f$'s values at a basis determines the function. Now, given this homogeneity constrain we observe that specifying $f(a,b)$ determines $f$ along the entire ray by $(a,b)$ but nowhere else. So let's choose a value of $f(a,b)$ for every $(a,b)$ on the unit circle and such that $f(-a,-b) = -f(a,b)$. Then by scaling we have a function on the whole plane satisfying your constraint.

Now, final problem: figure out which values on the unit circle give linear functions (or equivalently, what values do we get on the unit circle if we start with a linear function). Choose something that isn't that.